# cannot move cursor to external monitor

Tags: 13.04, multiple-monitors, laptop, screen, cursor

I just connected my external monitor and it all works fine. I tested this even in windows. But on ubuntu I cannot take the cursor to the external monitor. It just doesn't move there and it gets stuck at the laptop screen boundary. I cannot move it beyond that.

Comment: There are several possibilities: what is your screen configuration (how are they arranged in System settings > Screens)? Could you post an image of the "Screens" window? If they are arranged misaligned you could be moving into a "wall", they could be aligned different from what you think. Also try switching off sticky edges (or whatever it is called in English; "Plakranden" in Dutch). Please let me know.

Comment: You can drag and drop the screens in System Settings->Displays. Sometimes you can't move to your right monitor just because internally it's on the left side of your primary display.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most likely one of these situations is the case (In the example, HP 22" is my main screen)

#### The screen is misaligned or in another position than you assume

Open System settings > Screens:

*1. the screen is misaligned*

[image: Misaligned top-right]

*2. the screen is positioned differently from what you assume: on the left side..*

[image: Misaligned left]

*... or on top:*

[image: Misaligned top]

Simply drag the window in another position if one of these situations is the case.

#### Sticky edges

Another thing that makes it easier to move from one screen to another is switching the "Sticky edges" ("plakranden" in the screen shot below) option to *off*:

[image: Sticky edged]

Comment: An edit *and* an upvote!  ("Sticky edges" is idd de correcte benaming in het EN)

Comment: Sticky edges was my problem.

Comment: Moving the screen worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks in System Settings - > Displays how configuration of your system looks like. 
If all is okay and it looks like you predicted then try to move your mouse fast, sometimes my screen may not work for some reasons even if I know that I'm on the level of the screen I need. If all of it isn't work problem may be with the cabal change your hdmi/dvi or other.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility (which is rare) is there are some space between monitors. This means, even though left and right monitor are aligned with each other, there are some tiny space between these two. In my case, it is about 2.5mm visible space on my 24"in wide screen. So it feels like hard to move between boundaries. What actually happens is that cursor is moving in those ghost space area you can't see and therefore cause the delay.

The fix is to make sure monitor are really side by side on your 'display' setting.